# Локальный стор mobx не вызывает ререндер компонента. react

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

Есть компонент, который использует локальный и глобиальные mobx сторы. Не понимаю почему, но изменение значения в локальном сторе - `filters` не вызывает ререндер компонента, а если точнее, то повторный вызов `useEffect(() => { fetchAllTasks(filters) }, [fetchAllTasks, filters])`.

Стор:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx'

import { type GetTasksFilters, type OptionalGetTasksFilters } from '@/shared/api/tasks'

type FilterName = keyof GetTasksFilters

export class TasksFiltersStore {
  public filters: OptionalGetTasksFilters = {}

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  public readonly setOptionalGetTasksFilter = <T extends FilterName>(
    filterName: T,
    value: GetTasksFilters[T] | null,
  ) => {
    const temp = { ...this.filters }
    if (value === null) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-dynamic-delete
      delete temp[filterName]
    } else {
      temp[filterName] = value
    }

    this.filters = temp
  }
}
```

Компонент:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { Stack, type SxProps } from '@mui/material'
import { type Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { observer, useLocalObservable } from 'mobx-react-lite'

import { type UserOption, UsersFilter } from '@/features/tasks/filters'
import { NOT_ASSIGNED_USER_FILTER_VALUE } from '@/shared/api/tasks'
import { LOCALES } from '@/shared/lib/locales.ts'
import { useRootStore } from '@/stores/useRootStore.ts'
import { NOT_ASSIGNED_USER_ID } from '@/widgets/TasksFilters/model/constants.ts'
import { TasksFiltersStore } from '@/widgets/TasksFilters/model/store.ts'

const TasksFilters = observer(() => {
  const { filters, setOptionalGetTasksFilter } = useLocalObservable(() => new TasksFiltersStore())

  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const {
    tasksStore: { fetchAllTasks },
  } = useRootStore()

  const [assignedTo, setAssignedTo] = useState<UserOption | null>(null)
  const [createdBy, setCreatedBy] = useState<UserOption | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filters)
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
    fetchAllTasks(filters)
  }, [fetchAllTasks, filters])

  useEffect(() => {
    setOptionalGetTasksFilter(
      'assignedTo',
      (assignedTo?.id === NOT_ASSIGNED_USER_ID ? NOT_ASSIGNED_USER_FILTER_VALUE : assignedTo?.id) ??
        null,
    )
  }, [assignedTo, setOptionalGetTasksFilter])

  useEffect(() => {
    setOptionalGetTasksFilter('createdBy', createdBy?.id ?? null)
  }, [createdBy, setOptionalGetTasksFilter])

  return (
    <Stack sx={filtersContainerStyles} spacing={1}>
      <UsersFilter
        label={t(LOCALES.ASSIGNED_TO)}
        value={assignedTo}
        onChange={setAssignedTo}
        additionalOptions={[
          {
            id: NOT_ASSIGNED_USER_ID,
            label: t(LOCALES.NOT_ASSIGNED_TASKS),
          },
        ]}
      />
      <UsersFilter label={t(LOCALES.CREATED_BY)} value={createdBy} onChange={setCreatedBy} />
    </Stack>
  )
})

const filtersContainerStyles: SxProps<Theme> = {
  width: '100%',
}

export default TasksFilters
```

Comment: Глобальный стор нужно изменять в методах `mobx`... Локальный - соответствующей функцией. Если рендера нет - значит этого не сделали либо стор не обновлен правильно.

Comment: @ksa, Понял. Спасибо